# Angular 2 - named router-outlet routing in submodule

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router-outlet

I try use named router-outlet inside of submodule on my application, but when I put them inside of submodule I get error of missing routes:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard/dashboard'
```

There is a example, where 'aux' outlet in main app level workin good, but when I put 'auxdash' outlet in Dashboard module dosen't wotk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1VXpKqbVVZnOLRLtpoxY?p=preview

The problem was that I had to leave the path property empty like this:

```
{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent, outlet: 'auxdash' }
```

**What I do wrong, or this is some bug in Angular2 routing?**